# How can you possibly write test case for boolean in mockito, spring mvc environment

Tags: spring-mvc, mockito, springmockito

How can I possibly write test case for boolean in mockito, spring mvc environment

For e.g, like the following response

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
          Status = 200
   Error message = null
         Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]}
    Content type = application/json;charset=UTF-8
            Body = {"name":"myName","DOB":"12345"}
   Forwarded URL = null
  Redirected URL = null
         Cookies = []
```

We would write the test case like,

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/reqMapping/methodName"))
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8")) 
                    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name",comparesEqualTo("myName"); 
                    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.DOB",comparesEqualTo("12345");
```

Right? But, when we got the response like follow

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
          Status = 200
   Error message = null
         Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]}
    Content type = application/json;charset=UTF-8
            **Body = true**
   Forwarded URL = null
  Redirected URL = null
         Cookies = []
```

How should I write the test case?

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/reqMapping/methodName"))
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8")) 
                    .andExpect(???);
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

All you need to do is the following:

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/reqMapping/methodName"))
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8")) 
                    .andExpect(content().string("true");
```

The meat of the above code the is the `string` method of `ContentResultMatchers` (returned by `content()`).

[Here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/result/ContentResultMatchers.html#string-java.lang.String-) is the relevant javadoc